# Kubernetes projected service account token expiry time issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, openid-connect, amazon-eks

I'm using AWS EKS 1.21 with service account discovery enabled.
Created an OIDC provider, the `.well-known/openid-configuration` endpoint returns a correct configuration:

```
{
  "issuer": "https://oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/***",
  "jwks_uri": "https://ip-***.eu-west-1.compute.internal:443/openid/v1/jwks",
  "response_types_supported": [
    "id_token"
  ],
  "subject_types_supported": [
    "public"
  ],
  "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "RS256"
  ]
}
```

Created a ServiceAccount for one of my deployments and the pod gets this as projected volume:

```
  volumes:
  - name: kube-api-access-b4xt9
    projected:
      defaultMode: 420
      sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          expirationSeconds: 3607
          path: token
      - configMap:
          items:
          - key: ca.crt
            path: ca.crt
          name: kube-root-ca.crt
      - downwardAPI:
          items:
          - fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            path: namespace
```

The secret created for the ServiceAccount contains this token:

```
{
  "iss": "kubernetes/serviceaccount",
  "kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace": "sbx",
  "kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/secret.name": "dliver-site-config-service-token-kz874",
  "kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/service-account.name": "dliver-site-config-service",
  "kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/service-account.uid": "c26ad760-9067-4d90-a327-b3d6e32bce42",
  "sub": "system:serviceaccount:sbx:dliver-site-config-service"
}
```

The projected token mounted in to the pod contains this:

```
{
  "aud": [
    "https://kubernetes.default.svc"
  ],
  "exp": 1664448004,
  "iat": 1632912004,
  "iss": "https://oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/***",
  "kubernetes.io": {
    "namespace": "sbx",
    "pod": {
      "name": "dliver-site-config-service-77494b8fdd-45pxw",
      "uid": "0dd440a6-1213-4faa-a69e-398b83d2dd6b"
    },
    "serviceaccount": {
      "name": "dliver-site-config-service",
      "uid": "c26ad760-9067-4d90-a327-b3d6e32bce42"
    },
    "warnafter": 1632915611
  },
  "nbf": 1632912004,
  "sub": "system:serviceaccount:sbx:dliver-site-config-service"
}
```

Kubernetes renew the projected token every hour, so everything looks fine.
Except the projected token "exp" field:
`"iat": 1632912004` which is `Wednesday, September 29, 2021 10:40:04 AM`
`"exp": 1664448004` which is `Thursday, September 29, 2022 10:40:04 AM`

So the problem is, that the projected token expiry time is 1 year, instead of around 1 hour, which makes Kubernetes effort to renew the token basically useless.
I searched for hours but was simply unable to figure out where this is coming from.
The expiration flag is passed to the kube-api server: `--service-account-max-token-expiration="24h0m0s"`, so
my assumption is that this should be configured on the OIDC provider somehow, but unable to find any related documentation.

Any idea how to make the projected token expiry date around the same as the `expirationSeconds` in the pod projected volume?

### Update

It only happens, when the projected token `expirationSeconds` is set to the default `3607` value, any other value gives the correct `exp` in the mounted token, which is really weird.

Comment: What is the OIDC application you used? `https://ip-***.eu-west-1.compute.internal:443/openid/v1/jwks`

Comment: Just created the EKS cluster and associated the OIDC provider in IAM as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/enable-iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html

Comment: What is the benefit of getting a token for `kubernetes.default.svc` vs the default token automatically mounted by k8s? Especially you refer the OIDC of your own cluster.

Comment: This feature is by default enabled in EKS, because it's automatically sets the necessary flags, described here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#service-account-token-volume-projection.
In this case k8s will mount a projected token by default.
The benefit is, that we can use short lived tokens, instead of the long lived default token.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally got an answer [elsewhere](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/105654#issuecomment-942777567).

> cluster operators can specify flag --service-account-extend-token-expiration=true to kube apiserver to allow tokens have longer expiration temporarily during the migration. Any usage of legacy token will be recorded in both metrics and audit logs.

The "3607" magic number is part of the Bound Service Account Tokens safe rollout plan, [described in this kep](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-auth/1205-bound-service-account-tokens/README.md#safe-rollout-of-time-bound-token).
The actual number [hardcoded in the source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/ea0764452222146c47ec826977f49d7001b0ea8c/pkg/serviceaccount/claims.go#L35).
The `--service-account-extend-token-expiration` flag was [set to true](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/96273) by default from 1.20.

The mentioned metric/log info can be found [in the kep too](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/master/keps/sig-auth/1205-bound-service-account-tokens/README.md#serviceaccount-admission-controller-migration) and was implemented [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/89549).
To see these logs in EKS need to [enable audit logging on the cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/control-plane-logs.html), then check Cloudwatch for related log entries.

I used this query in Cloudwatch Log Insight to find which pods don't reload the token periodically:

```kotlin
filter @logStream like 'kube-apiserver-audit'
 | filter ispresent(`annotations.authentication.k8s.io/stale-token`)
 | parse `annotations.authentication.k8s.io/stale-token` "subject: *," as subject
 | stats count(*) as staleCount by subject, `user.username`
 | sort staleCount desc
```